# Mappings for Project Sidebar with IdeaVim

Tags: clion, ideavim

I've got some experience with this cool IdeaVim plugin and CLion and was pretty satisfied with it, but I am having a trouble which torments me at the moment.

Is there an ability to add custom mappings which could work in Project Tool Window? I have "set NERDTree" option in my .ideavimrc, but it seems there is no vim-way shorcuts for creating new files and some other useful actions.